# React Native Android app working fine on debug mode but when we are releasing apk it's generating older version of the app

Tags: android, react-native

React Native Android app working fine on debug mode but when we are releasing apk it's generating older version of the app.

android/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 32
        targetSdkVersion = 32
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1"
         kotlin_version='1.6.0' //add This change version with your installed kotlin version

    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
                  
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2")
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" //add This
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

android/grdle/gradle-wrapper.properties

```
 distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**-------------- Apk issues resolve after gradle upgrade -----------------**

**Step-1:**

- Remove `android/.gradle` folder
- Remove `android/build` folder
- Remove `android/app/build` folder
- Remove .jso folder   -- If present, it is used to perform obfuscation
- Remove android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle file

**Step-2:**

Then we have to create `index.android.bundle` again for that run the below command.

```
npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

Then it will create the following files and folders:

- android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle.
- android/app/src/main/res/drawable*

**Step-3**

- Remove `android/app/src/main/res/drawable*` folders

Then generate release APK with this command

- `cd android && gradlew assembleRelease`